# is it possible to redireact the cargo build output log

Tags: linux, rust-cargo

I want to output the cargo build log to a file, then I use the command like this:

```
cargo build --verbose > build.log
```

after the command runs complete, I did not found the content from build.log.

```
> ls -alh|grep build
-rw-r--r--   1 xiaoqiangjiang  staff     0B Oct 10 14:14 build.log
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to output the build log to the file?

Comment: I tried including `stderr` like `cargo build --verbose &> build.log` and it worked.

Comment: why the cargo default output is stderr not stdout?

Comment: Most all warning and error output is on `stderr` allowing you to separate normal program output from warnings and errors.